# Minor correction for flag weight audit page

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flag-history

When user A views the flag weight audit page for user B, there is a section titled "Your flagging history"; but when A ≠ B it should say "This user's flagging history" (or equivalent).

Ah, I forgot that only moderators can review other user's flagging history (I am a mod on math.SE which is where I noticed this issue). That makes this even lower priority I suppose.

Comment: How do you view someone else's flag weight? It doesn't let me. When I try replacing my user ID in my flag weight URL with another user's ID, it just says page not found.

Comment: @animuson Could it be a rep thing? (on mobile now; can't verify)

Comment: also, Zev is a community moderator on Math.

Comment: **Only diamond mods** can see flag weight of other users - anyone can see their own.

Comment: Considering flag weight is long gone, I'm going to `status-declined` this request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that affects only perhaps 3 users per site, save a few large sites. As such, I don't think a change in the code is necessary for something as small as this.

There are several other little things that aren't changed. For e.g., it says "my logins" when you check the login credentials of a user and if you edit their profile, it says "about me" in the text box. I've always thought of it as 'This is how it appears to the user', and have learned to live with the small inconsistencies.